# Twitter like newsfeed using Firebase

Tags: firebase

I am playing around with Firebase. I have a question to the firebase community.

How to structure the data for newsfeed(e.g. like twitter) in firebase? I didn't find any results in Google. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Firebase is a large suite of developer products that allows you to build pretty much any application. For a good example of something akin to twitter built on the Firebase Database, see https://firefeed.io/. But aside from that I'm going to vote to close this question as being too broad.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen. Now i know that there is no limitation in firebase.

Answer (score 1):

There's a guide that explains that you should de-normalize your data in json database.

[Structurig your data (guide)](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html)
&
[Denormalizing Your Data is Normal (article)](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html)